# Burninate [large-data] tag or merge it with [bigdata]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[Big data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data) is an industry term for when the size of the data is significant enough that it becomes a factor in your code, software, architecture, etc., etc.

Large data is what you'd call it if you didn't know there was already a widely used term in place for it.

The [large-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/large-data) tag has **23** followers. The [bigdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdata) tag has **11,800** followers and about five times as many questions. Should we merge the former into the latter or something?

Comment: Some of the questions I see tagged [[tag:large-data]] are not actually about [[tag:bigdata]]... Or, at least, ~2 GB is not what *I* consider to be big data. I also spotted one that is asking about [the large code model](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/03/understanding-the-x64-code-models), which should be a different tag entirely (but I think that's a very isolated case and mostly due to my personal favorited tags).

Comment: @CodyGray Fair enough. I will just add that I used to hear a lot of people debate "how big is big" but it seems like the eventual (semi-) consensus is just that it's "big" if the size is causing you an issue. So if you're using a Commodore 64 then 10 MB could be "big" IMHO. Just my 2 cents though, I'm sure some would disagree.

Answer (score 6):

Large data isn't the same as the buzzword.  From what I'm seeing of these questions, they pertain to a specific and valid subset of development, which involves loading large amounts of data into memory.

Big data is more about the analysis and storage of large data more than it is in loading data into memory at a given time.

However...is [bigdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdata) even useful?  I'm not entirely certain it is.  It doesn't describe a specific thing and it as a concept itself is incredibly broad...if an asker has a question involving a big data library, then surely they'd be using that library's tag instead of this one.

Gut tells me that [bigdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdata) should be burninated and [large-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/large-data) can stay where it is now.

Comment: But Big Data is the widely used term defined in dictionaries with billions of dollars being spent around it and entire technologies and languages created around it... large data is practically just a typo, doesn't mean anything specific and only has 23 followers...

Comment: @Hack-R:  ...and yet it describes nothing.  Are you talking about big data warehousing (like data lakes)?  Big data analysis with libraries such as Hadoop?  Neither can be fully covered by that tag alone, regardless of how many billions of dollars its has to its name.