# When/why does bulk tagging happen?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed there is a post which contains a [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37247711/revisions) described as

> added [bigdata] to 2621 questions - Shog9 (Id=811)

Just wondering why that happened and whether there was any meta discussion? When would this sort of mass tag adding happen? Especially as the [bigdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdata) tag is a bit meaningless, adding it to 2621 questions seems pointless enough.

Comment: Perhaps someone decided to burninate the tag without meta discussion and an employee decided to re-add the tag.

Comment: Maybe related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356201/burninate-large-data-tag-or-merge-it-with-bigdata timeline wise this is possible

Comment: This is related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because some users take it on themselves to do [a tag burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta).

And then some poor soul has to [undo all that](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/mass-tagging-tool).

That is why [having a process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071) as well as [a civil discourse on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) about tag changes is preferred, if not mandatory.

Comment: Is that what happened to that *specific* tag as well? Because majority of such-tagged questions contain, but aren't about, or just mention it, but hardly ever touch the subject as per tag description (which is quite broad already); many feel a feeble few thousand records is [bigdata], want to know "*How do I search and replace in [hadoop]?*" (and the like) or are completely unrelated, too broad "*Optimize this WordPress MySQL query's runtime for me?!*" -like questions. Quite some of those carry Shog9's notice. It's a meaningless buzz-word as well.

Comment: @user4157124 sure. That is why I linked in my comment to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356201/burninate-large-data-tag-or-merge-it-with-bigdata . That post doesn't "scream" let's remove that tag. If you have a strong case to remove that tag, bring it on in a Meta post and then **wait** for consensus. Do not take it on by yourself to remove a tag from thousands of questions in one seating.