# Why are these two totally unrelated questions linked?

Tags: bug, questions, specific-question, linked-questions

[Ruby net/http/get does not work with url's, but works with uri's. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65952596/2988) has [How do I set an Electron variable at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65798852/2988) as its only linked question, and vice versa, the latter has the former as one of two linked questions.

I cannot really see any reason why they would be linked, though. Neither is mentioned in any of the question, answers, or comments of the other, nor do there appear to be any duplicate votes. I also checked the edit histories of both questions and all answers.

So, why *are* they linked? Note: I am specifically talking about the *linked* questions which require an explicit user action and not the *related* questions which are algorithmically determined.

Comment: That question does use the url of that linked question as an example in their code and so does the (edited) comment. If either of those missed a code-block tick / markdown they might have triggered the "add linked post" feature.

Comment: Cross site (though not a post - a tag / tag wiki): *[Linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/linked-questions/info)*. The blog post announcing it (2010): *[New Linked Posts](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/26/new-linked-posts/)*. Also (two days after the blog post) *[Whoa! What is this “Linked” thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48076)*.

Comment: Tag as a bug?...

Comment: Re-tagged the question as a [tag:bug], after the investigation done by rene and fedorqui.

Comment: Interestingly, it's smart enough not to replace the link in the question with an anchor tag with the title as text, so there must be logic somewhere that checks suitability for that in the link-making routine, just not in the Linked-Questions-populating routine. Good eye.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me try adding something in code that is not a direct link to see if we have a bug (or at least a surprising feature).

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392303/i-have-a-question-about-my-stack-overflow-post
```

that ^ should not link.

Unfortunately it does add a row to the Linked section.

[image]

So ...

Looking at the SO question you linked to:

[image: link in code]

Anything that looks like an URL that points to a valid post will lead to that URL being added to the Linked section of a post.

That is bug-ish.

Comment: It is a link...[[meta-tag:bug]]?

Comment: Does it happen in comments as well? Let's test ---> `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404808/`. Edit: yes, it does link to the question I link in the comment.

Comment: Re-tagged the question as [tag:bug]. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I expect status-bydesign but I agree on *let's see what happens*